# jQuery UI tabs conflicting with jquery slider in every browser except firefox - multiple jQuery instances

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've been attempting to add jQuery UI tabs to a page using a jquery slider plugin. It looks good in Firefox, but in every other browser the slider isn't working. Also, the slider only work in ff with multiple instances of jQuery (which I know is bad). Also, I'm running google feed control in the tabs.  The relevant code is pasted below. you can also see the page at http://bit.ly/M0xIMM and the slider js here: http://bit.ly/KAe8Mf Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){
          var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

          if (i != totalSize) {
              next = i + 2;
                  $(this).append("");
          }

          if (i != 0) {
              prev = i;
              $(this).append("");
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/rhuk_milkyway/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/mod_ds_banner_slide/mod_ds_banner_slide/mbScrollable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dsbs_Homebanner").mbScrollable({
        width: 950,
        elementsInPage: 1,
        elementMargin: 4,
        height: 175,
        controls: "#dsbs_Homebannercontrols",
        slideTimer: 600,
        autoscroll: true,
        scrollTimer: 6000        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you recreate this on a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that is easier to read?  Removing code that doesn't apply to the problem would help as well.

Comment: Hi, I removed some of the excess code that isn't causing the problem, I'll try to reformat it with jsfiddle, though I'm not totally sure how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are including jquery-1.3.2.min.j twice?

Comment: yes, I'm including it twice. When I remove the second inclusion it breaks the tabs in ff and doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of jQuery with a new version of UI.  Just use the latest stable version of jQuery and eliminate both of the 1.3.2's.  You don't need to be calling any scripts in the `head` (except maybe Google Analytics).  Put all of that Javascript at the end of the `body`.  Mootools is likely conflicting with jQuery.  Make sure you call [Mootools first](http://www.alltogetherasawhole.org/profiles/blogs/preventing-jquery-and-mootools)

Comment: Also, it looks like the Joomla template you're using might be poorly coded to begin with or not entirely compatible with your CMS version http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=583122

Comment: You need to plug it all into a fiddle or give a url because this isn't enough info to solve it

Comment: Hmm. I called mootools first and still no luck. Even tried removing it and that didn't fix it either. Thanks though.